# Could not open settings generic class cache for settings

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio

hi i'm getting this error in android studion windows 10 any solution?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\acer\StudioProjects\untitled2\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\acer\.gradle\caches\7.5\scripts\3d075fs9hjp81ny0sgym4v09w).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 63

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 919ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

- Go to **wrapper** directory  **android >> gradle** folder.
- Delete ***gradle-wrapper.jar*** file
- Edit ***gradle-wrapper.properties*** file
- Sync project

  ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip or latest
  ```